# Get Array of Latest txg Values and Uberblocks Using zdb on a ZFS Pool

Tags: zfs, zdb

Can import pool. How can I find the a list of older `txg` values using `zdb`, so I can attempt to rollback to one of those versions.

Comment: Just putting this here because I couldn't find it anywhere, or in the manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will dump an array of 32 Uberblocks, along with their dates and `txg` values.

```
$ zdb -e darkpool -ul
        ...
        Uberblock[0]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227136
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580010 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:00:10 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[1]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226049
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580574611 UTC = Sat Feb  1 11:30:11 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[2]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23225890
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580573825 UTC = Sat Feb  1 11:17:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[3]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23225891
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580573826 UTC = Sat Feb  1 11:17:06 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[4]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23225892
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580573832 UTC = Sat Feb  1 11:17:12 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[5]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226405
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580576402 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:00:02 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[6]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226950
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580579102 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:45:02 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[7]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226951
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580579103 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:45:03 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[8]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226952
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580579104 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:45:04 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[9]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226953
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580579105 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:45:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[10]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226954
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580579106 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:45:06 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[11]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227339
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580581022 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:17:02 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[12]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227340
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580581023 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:17:03 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[13]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227341
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580581024 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:17:04 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[14]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227342
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580581025 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:17:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[15]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227343
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580581025 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:17:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[16]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227344
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580581026 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:17:06 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[17]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227345
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580581031 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:17:11 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[18]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227314
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580903 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:15:03 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[19]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227315
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580904 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:15:04 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[20]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227316
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580905 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:15:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[21]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227317
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580910 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:15:10 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[22]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226774
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580578205 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:30:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[23]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226775
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580578206 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:30:06 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[24]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226776
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580578211 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:30:11 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[25]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23226617
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580577425 UTC = Sat Feb  1 12:17:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[26]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227130
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580001 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:00:01 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[27]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227131
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580002 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:00:02 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[28]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227132
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580003 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:00:03 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[29]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227133
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580003 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:00:03 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[30]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227134
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580004 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:00:04 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        Uberblock[31]
        magic = 0000000000bab10c
        version = 5000
        txg = 23227135
        guid_sum = 14295331914005933530
        timestamp = 1580580005 UTC = Sat Feb  1 13:00:05 2020
        mmp_magic = 00000000a11cea11
        mmp_delay = 0
            labels = 0 1 2 3 
        ...
```